# How to find sum and convergence of series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^{2}\cdot(2n+1)^{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I laid this shot that: 
$$\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}=1/4\, \left( 2\,n+1 \right) ^{-2}-1/4\, \left( 2\,n-1 \right) ^{-1}+1/
4\, \left( 2\,n-1 \right) ^{-2}+1/4\, \left( 2\,n+1 \right) ^{-1}
$$
But I don't know what to do next. Help me please

Comment: you must compute the sum of These sumands

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner And what to do when one series converged and the other one disconverged

Comment: Note that the denominator is $$\Big((2n-1)(2n+1)\Big)^2 = (4n^2-1)^2$$  So your series can be written as $$\sum \frac1{(4n^2 - 1)^2}$$

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for a hint

Comment: @amWhy Is it must help me?

Comment: ok you will Need the partial sum,right?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes)

Comment: but the partial sum containes the Digamma function

Comment: the infinite sum is given by $$\frac{1}{16} \left(\pi ^2-8\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you explained me about Digamma function?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How did you count this, can you explain more detailed

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I found info about Digamma function, but I didn't understand this, can you explain it in my example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n+1}$$

Thus, your series reduces as follows:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}=-\frac12+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}$$

Since everything cancels except that.  Now let $S$ be the following sum:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$

It can be seen that

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1{(2n-1)^2}+\frac1{(2n)^2}\right]=\frac14S+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}=\frac34S=\frac{\pi^2}8$$

and finally,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}=-\frac12+\frac12\left(\frac{\pi^2}8\right)=\frac{\pi^2-8}{16}$$

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for detailed explanation)

Comment: No problem!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

By partial fraction decomposition
$$ \frac{1}{(2x-1)^2 (2x+1)^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{16}}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{x-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{x+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{\frac{1}{16}}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} \tag{1}$$
hence it follows that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2 (2n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^2-8}{16}}\tag{2}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't understand why answer $$ =\frac{\pi^{2} - 8}{16}$$

Comment: @J.Joshua: the value of the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ is well-known.