# Infinite series for these two values.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I know that if I want a infinite series whose result is $4$, I could do something like this:

$$ 
4= \dfrac{1}{1/4} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{4-3}{4}} = \dfrac{1}{1 -\dfrac{3}{4}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{3}{4} \right)^n,
$$

using the famous relation:

$$
\dfrac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n, \quad |x| < 1.
$$

I think this works for every rational number. Another example is a infinite series whose result is $\sqrt 2$, as shown by this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/694814/184476):

$$
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt2 =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{4^kk!}.
\end{equation*}
$$

There are some infinite series involving $\pi$ such as:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2} &= \dfrac{\pi^2}{6},\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1} &= \dfrac{\pi}{4}, \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4} &= \dfrac{\pi^4}{90}, \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2 n-1)^3} = &= \dfrac{\pi^3}{32}.
\end{align}
$$

Just like this, I would like to know if there is a infinite series with rational terms for:

$$
\dfrac{\pi^2 - 8}{16} = \sum \text{Some expression}
$$

and for:

$$
\dfrac{3 \pi^3 \sqrt 2}{16} = \sum \text{Some expression}.
$$

Comment: For any real number  $a$ the series $ a+0+0+..$ converges to $a$. Your questioin does not make sense.

Comment: $\dfrac{6}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right) = \dfrac{6}{16}\dfrac{(\pi)^2}{6} = \dfrac{(\pi)^2}{16}.$  This is as close as I can come.

Comment: I presume you’re only looking for series with rational terms.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2-8}{16}$   (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289063/how-to-find-sum-and-convergence-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n-1)).

$\displaystyle 8\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+1)^3} = \frac{3\pi^3 \sqrt{2}}{16}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792065/integral-int-0-infty-log2-x-frac1x21x4dx-frac3-pi316-sqrt-2/867937#867937)).

Comment: @NoName Please write that as the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @David Okay, I’ve unearthed my earlier answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2-8}{16}$   (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289063/how-to-find-sum-and-convergence-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n-1)).

$\displaystyle 8\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+1)^3} = \frac{3\pi^3 \sqrt{2}}{16}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792065/integral-int-0-infty-log2-x-frac1x21x4dx-frac3-pi316-sqrt-2/867937#867937)).

Answer (score 1):

For any real number $a$ and any integer $b$, we have

$$a = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\lfloor b^n a\rfloor - b\lfloor b^{n-1} a\rfloor}{b^n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer will be trivial as compared to other's but still with my high-school knowledge , I can answer your first part-

$(6/16)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ((1/n^2-4/(3.2^n))= (\pi^2-8)/16 $